# Unable to open link within same tab using Cypress

Tags: jquery, tabs, cypress, href

In our web page, we have various links that open in a new tab, but obviously we need to open them in the same tab when using Cypress.

I've tried

```
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').eq(index).invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

but this still opens the URL in a new tab.

I've also tried adding `find('a')`  :

```
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').eq(index).find('a').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

but the page never loads (I've tried increasing the timeout as well but it still fails).

I would like to get the above to work, but I've also found this alternative which works, so I guess I'm confused by this code below works but I can't get the invoke to work.

```
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').eq(index).find('a').then(link => {
                   cy.request(link.prop('href')).its('status').should('eq', 200)
```

Any feedback is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: How is your HTML look alike that you try to click? Is there a `target="_blank"`?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes, there is a `target="_blank"`

Comment: Julia, that seems to be the problem. What happens if you remove it from the HTML that you have using the dev tools?

Comment: It would help us if you could paste HTML of the element that opens a new tab.

Comment: @LajosArpad if I remove the target via dev tools, the link properly opens in the same browser tab. But this doesn't happen when I use `invoke('removeAttr', 'target')`

Comment: How did you try to call that invoke? Can you edit your question with the current try?

Comment: @LajosArpad
`cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').eq(index).find('a').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general recipe for this is

```js
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').eq(index).find('a')
  .then($el => {
     expect($el).to.have.attr('target','_blank')
     // update attr to open in same tab
     $el.attr('target', '_self')
  })
  .click()
```

The `_self` value may not always be required, but the other aspect is timing as you are updating the DOM.

You could also try this

```js
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').eq(index).find('a')
  .invoke('attr', 'href').then(myLink => {
    cy.visit(myLink);
  })
```

---

**Cross origin**

See this blog [Stub window.open](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/stub-window-open/), shows a way to stub the window open.

```js
let stub    // variable that will hold cy.stub created in the test

Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
  if (stub) {
    Object.defineProperty(win, 'open', {
      get() {
        return stub
      }
    })
  }
})

beforeEach(() => {
  stub = null
})

const href = 'url/that/link/takes/you to'

it('check that window open was called', () => {

  cy.visit('/')  // not stubbing this

  stub = cy.stub().as('open')
  
  cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').eq(index).find('a')
    .click()    // trigger window.open

  cy.get('@open')
    .should('have.been.calledWith', href)   // check href is called

})

it('tests the link page further', () => {
  cy.visit(href)
  // continue tests
})
```

If your href is a changeable, you can grab it in a beforeEach

```js
beforeEach(() => cy.visit('/'))

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').eq(index)
    .find('a').invoke('attr', 'href').as('href')   // link value into an alias
})

it('check that window open was called', () => {

  cy.get('@href').then(href => {
 
    stub = cy.stub().as('open')
  
    cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').eq(index).find('a')
      .click()    // trigger window.open

    cy.get('@open')
      .should('have.been.calledWith', href)   // check href is called
  })
})

it('tests the link page further', () => {
  cy.get('@href').then(href => {
    cy.visit(href)
    // continue tests
  })
})
```

Comment: Hm the general recipe doesn't work. The page never loads and the test fails.

The second method doesn't work for me because the URL doesn't have the same origin URL.

Comment: Cross domain will work in separate tests, so you need to break into two parts.